# AIDE compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'

Tags: android, compilation, android-appcompat, aide

I'm having trouble compiling `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'` on AIDE

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.0"

defaultConfig {
application "com.mycompany.myapp"
minSdkVersion 14
targetSdkVersion 21
versionCode 1
versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
release {
minifyEnabled false
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
}
}
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
}
```

**Error**

```
Dependency com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+ not found.
```

I've searched on Stack Overflow for others that have had the same issue with AIDE to no avail.

Comment: [An article](http://blog.danlew.net/2015/09/09/dont-use-dynamic-versions-for-your-dependencies/) about why you shouldn't do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out, I hadn't included mavenCentral() in my repositories.

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
            mavenCentral()
}
```

}